# Firestore Database Structuring

Tags: android, database-design, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a social app that lets users add posts based on the country code. For main feed, I will fetch posts of every country posts based on timestamp. For example, if you are in Turkey, only posts within Turkey will show up in your feed. There is no follower/ following system.

Should I store all posts in one `posts` collection with the country code field? Or it is more flexible to group them as `posts/countryCode/posts`. I just don't know if firestore is powerful enough to query all posts for specific country code and timestamp.

What is the best approach for flexibility and pricing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For only what you're describing here, it actually doesn't matter at all what you choose.

Pricing is based on the number of documents read in a query.  That's not going to change in either case.

If all you want to do is query by country code, it doesn't matter if you put everything in one collection, or use subcollections with a collection group query.  As long as the country code is a field in the document, either way, you will be able to filter for only that code.

Choose whatever one you are more comfortable with.